# How can I add and drop columns and rows in a pandas dataframe followed by saving it down into a csv (adding and dropping works but doesn't save)?

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have some code that drops a few columns in a pandas dataframe and add one column to the pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('TradedInstrument_20230331_real.txt',  sep='\t', encoding='unicode_escape')

cols = ['stopTrdgAllag', 'stopTrdgsAllowTrdg', 'stopTrdleInTrdg', 'presholdChf', 'billentCode', 'preTradeBsholdChf', 'billinntDesc']

x = ['e'] * len(df.index)
df['new_col'] = x

df.drop(columns=cols).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

So what I am trying to do is add a new column `new_col` with `e` as entries in each row. And also to drop all of the columns that are in `cols`. While the code works fine to achieve this, when I run the above, in the output, only the columns are dropped and the row is NOT added!

I can kind of see why this is, it is because the `to_csv` only incorporates the dropping of the columns. So how can I add the adding of the new column too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify axis.
can you try
`df.drop(columns=cols,axis = 1).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`